# grails Spring security custom permission in controller

Tags: grails, spring-security

I want to create a custom permission handler using grails spring security plugin.

Imagine I have a User class and a company class with a many-to-many association.

I want only allow users to call a method called "delete company" when they belong to the company. Example:

```
class User {

static hasMany= [companies:Company]
static belongsTo = [Company]

}

class Company {

static hasMany = [users:User]

}
```

the controller action looks like to following:

```
def deleteCompany(Long id) {

}
```

I only want to allow users to call the method that are part of the company. So when

```
assert Company.get(id}.users.find { it == currentUser }
```

This is just a simplified example. The actual structure is much more complex. That's why I want to use the power of spring security for this.

I already played around with spring security ACL but it seems that I can only use custom permissions in services but not in controllers

Answer (score 0):

You could use `beforeInterceptor` in your controller:

```
def springSecurityService
def beforeInterceptor=[action:this.&auth]
private auth = {
    def toBeCheckedId=params.id
    if(toBeCheckedId 
          && Company.get(toBeCheckedId}.users.find { it == springSecurityService.currentUser }){
            redirect action:someHandlingAction
            return false
        }
    }
}
```